# Two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs next to each other and this is working fine, but as you change the size of the browser or device I would like to have the second div underneath the first one but that doesn't work with this code.

Here is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/rvzthd6v/

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempor eu arcu quis tristique. Vestibulum vel odio scelerisque, placerat leo porttitor, dapibus sapien. Sed lacus ante, posuere eu mollis quis, interdum sit amet est. Aliquam tincidunt, arcu vitae pretium viverra, eros elit ultricies ante, in convallis ante erat sed nunc. Aliquam feugiat mollis lacinia. Nulla non dolor sit amet eros vehicula gravida ut ac nisi. Aliquam ut congue metus. Mauris id justo in arcu viverra lobortis. Duis dictum malesuada libero quis fermentum.      </div>
<div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tempor eu arcu quis tristique. Vestibulum vel odio scelerisque, placerat leo porttitor, dapibus sapien. Sed lacus ante, posuere eu mollis quis, interdum sit amet est. Aliquam tincidunt, arcu vitae pretium viverra, eros elit ultricies ante, in convallis ante erat sed nunc. Aliquam feugiat mollis lacinia. Nulla non dolor sit amet eros vehicula gravida ut ac nisi. Aliquam ut congue metus. Mauris id justo in arcu viverra lobortis. Duis dictum malesuada libero quis fermentum.</div>
```

```
div.wrap {clear:both; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}
div.one {float: left; border: 1px solid black; max-width: 40%; margin-right: 5%;}
div.two {float: left; max-width: 40%; border: 1px solid black;}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `min-width` you will achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/v393gd3o/

```
div.one {
     float: left; 
     border: 1px solid black; 
     min-width: 200px; 
     max-width: 40%; 
     margin-right: 5%;
}


div.two {
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px; 
    max-width: 40%; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To place one div underneath another you can user CSS [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You need to set  `<div class="wrap">` to  `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` and inner divs will be positioned next to each other.

Than you set  `<div class="wrap">` to `flex-direction: column` and inner divs will be placed in 'column' - one under another.

You can set such behaviour for different `@media` for ex.
Or check wrapper-div/browser size changes and switch from one to another styles.